# } expected and type or namespace definition or end of file expected

Tags: c#, console

```
public class CalculatorUI
{

        Calculator obj= new Calculator();

        public void Menu()
        {
            string choice;
            double value;
            double val1;
            double val2;

            System.Console.WriteLine("1: Addition");
            System.Console.WriteLine("2: Subtraction");
            System.Console.WriteLine("3: Multiplication");
            System.Console.WriteLine("4: Division");
            System.Console.WriteLine("5: Mod");
            System.Console.WriteLine("6: Square root");
            System.Console.WriteLine("0: Exit");

            System.Console.WriteLine("Select choice from menu: ");
            choice=System.Console.ReadLine();

            if(choice == 1)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Values: ");
                val1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                val2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                value =obj.Addition(val1 , val2);
            }
            else if(choice == 2)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Values: ");
                val1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                val2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                value =obj.Subtraction(val1 , val2);
            }
            else if(choice == 3)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Values: ");
                val1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                val2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                value =obj.Multiplication(val1 , val2);
            }
            else if(choice == 4)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Values: ");
                val1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                val2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                value =obj.Division(val1 , val2);
            }
            else if(choice == 5)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Values: ");
                val1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                val2 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                value =obj.Mod(val1 , val2);
            }
            else if(choice == 6)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Value for squareroot: ");
                val1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
                value =obj.SquareRoot(val1);
            }
            else
            { 
                System.Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
            }
        }

 public static void Main()
    { Menu();
    }
}
```

I'm working on notepad. all brackets are complete I have no idea about the error. it is not even compiling. I've made an object of another class named calculator which is compiled properly.
Edit done!
I'm working on notepad. all brackets are complete I have no idea about the error. it is not even compiling. I've made an object of another class named calculator which is compiled properly.

Comment: Working with notepad, seriously?

Comment: its a college first hw. no other choice

Comment: indentation would help with this.

Comment: @Mahrukh did you add a namespace declation or is that all the code in your file?

Comment: no! i didn't @Nasreddine

Comment: §Even for homework you should use a decent editor or online editor (and compiler) like [dotnetfiddle.net](http://dotnetfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Menu() method is inside the Main() method.

You should create Menu() as a separate method to Main(), call Menu() from Main() and pass the calculator object into it. Or merge Menu() into Main().

Comment: Different error or the same one?

Comment: different, now main is static and menu is not static.. a long list of errors

Comment: update your code in the question please.
if you want to be able to call Menu() without an instance of CalculatorUi it would have to be static